# Formatting numbers on a continuous axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to format the numbers on a continuous axis in a ggplot graph. I would like to have a French formatting for large numbers with a space every three digit (ie "20 000" instead of "20000"). I know it is possible to do it using the `format()` function (for instance `format(20000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark = " ")`) but I don't know how to combine this function with ggplot. I can imagine that there is an option in the `scale_y_continuous()` but I was unable to find the solution by myself. 
Here is my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/6342620).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
french = function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ")

p + scale_y_continuous(labels=french)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add it using `theme()`?